Integration Test fails to verify 2 KafkaReceiver flux at once
A microservice (with spring reactive) that is used to consume a kafka topic, and after some transformations, produces into another one. Some other topics are used in between for the transformation business and error handling.
I'm doing Integration Tests, using EmbeddedKafka. Here's an example:
@Test
void shipperbox_answers_internal_server_error_v2() {

    // Data generation
    final InputKey key = factory.defaultKey();
    final InputMessage message = factory.withPalletOneOrder();

    // Send to Input topic
    final SenderRecord<InputKey, InputMessage, Object> senderRecord = SenderRecord.create(new ProducerRecord<InputKey, InputMessage>(topic, 0, new Date().getTime(), key, message, factory.getDefaultHeaders()), null);
    inputSender
            .send(Mono.just(senderRecord))
            .subscribe();

    TestVerifier.checkFlux(rqConsumer.receive(), list -> list.size() == 4, 10);
    TestVerifier.checkFlux(dlqConsumer.receive(), list -> list.size() == 1, 10);
    
}

As for the code of checkFlux:
public static <T> void checkFlux(final Flux<T> flux, final java.util.function.Predicate<List<T>> verifyFunction, final Integer waitingTime) {
    StepVerifier.create(flux.buffer(Duration.ofSeconds(waitingTime)))
            .expectNextMatches(verifyFunction)
            .thenCancel()
            .verify();
}

With only one call of "TestVerifier.checkFlux", the test passes. With both calls, the test runs indefinitely. It seems that consuming 2 reactor kafka consumers on the test, provokes some resource contention or deadlock. But I have no idea how to deal with it.
I tried different approaches (publishOn parallel thread, subscribeOn, verify(Duration), ...) but none of them worked.
